# Remove Referrer Node JS

Tags: node.js, http, https

I am building a server as a middle-man to remove referrers as a project.

Is it possible to not pass ANY referrers before redirect using just nodeJS?

Here is my current (non-working complete) solution:

```
const referrerPolicy = require('referrer-policy')

app.use(referrerPolicy({
     policy: ['no-referrer']
}))

app.use(referrerPolicy())

app.use(setRefererToNull); 
    function setRefererToNull(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.headers.referer);
        req.headers.referer = null;
        next();
}
```